# Will rocksDB support nested keys for one value?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rocksdb, rocksdb-java

I am new to RocksDB. I am testing it on java spring boot(dependency: org.rocksdb.rocksdbjni). Will it support on storing nested keys for one value and retrieve a value using nested keys.

Example:
In Java, I am using the following data structure. Map<Type1, Map<Type2, Type3>>().
Will it workout in rocksDB implementation?. Here 'Type1' is the outer key, 'Type2' is the inner key and 'Type3' is the value for the respective keys.

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB does not support Map within a Map, you could look at other databases that are built over RocksDB.

Though One way you could represent Map within a Map is to use to keys with the following form:

```
"type1/type2/type3": value
```